# Is it possible for an NGINX stream to distinguish between 2 or more domains using the same port?

Tags: http, nginx, server, stream, reverse-proxy

I have an nginx server that I want to use to forward https requests coming into my local network from different subdomains. I want to route them to different local servers depending on the subdomain the request is for. The TLS certificates are not accessible from the nginx server (they live in the target local servers).

Currently, I am using a stream directive to forward the request to one of those server but I would like to add another one. My current working setup looks like this:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass <local_ip>:443;
    }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish something like this (in where I can route the request received in port 443 to a specific server depending on the domain it comes from):

```
map <domain_name> $match {
    <domain_1.com> "local_ip_1:443";
    <domain_2.com> "local_ip_2:443";
}

stream {
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass $match;
    }
}
```